# Icon on desktop but not on list

Tags: android, icons

I've made a few Android App with the launcher icon in drawable. Now, with the new Android Studio, it seems better to put it (or them) inside mipmap. So I've done that and get a problem:

The icon of the new App is visible on the desktop with the correct name, but in the Settings/Application List, the App has the default Android icon and the name is the dev path (eg com.ansb.reflexe rather than "Reflexo")
My Manifest is the same than for the older App so seems not to be the "reason why"

```
        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Any idea?

Comment: try uninstalling your app and install again. Also insure you add all sizes of the icon in mipmap

Comment: Does nothing. And I have all the sizes in mipmap.